# How to retain back to the last permission of file or directory

Tags: 14.04, permissions, scripts

I have accidentally changed the permission of a file now I want that file to back to the last permission state but how to do this?

Is there any procedure or tool or any command line script which keep tracks of all permission list of a specific folder

OR

We can see the numeric permission on context menu and also to set back to it's last permission?

Please suggest how to do it.

#### update

I know the alternative and basic approach: check the permission first and then set back.

Comment: @TheSchwa don't just search and paste the simlar question. what I have asked is same but the given answer is not the solution. and btw even the duplicate you suggested are not accepted as answer.So first please read properly. Don't you know askubuntu.com itself give suggestions before posting. I have read that all I read. I didnt find the solution ..all are alternative.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer to your question is indeed in that link. Specifically, as Jan has also noted below in his answer, you can't "undo" a file permissions change because Linux does not keep a record of them. Also please be polite, as everyone on this site is giving up their time to help you for free.

Comment: @TheSchwa when someone completely fed up then he comes to this site and as soon as one post the real world problem you started pasting the duplicate. I have seen the problem here. maximum questions have `This question may already have an answer here:`  label just before the original question . people will walk away to read. it may be ubuntu.com issue. but Please suggest as comment do not add on top.Thank you

Comment: @TheSchwa I am sorry for being rude but this already asked label really kills the soul of question. people will click to the duplicate and do not read the original question.

Comment: Marking a question as "duplicate" is just one of the ways askubuntu tries to stay organized and user friendly. Adding such a comment does not stop other uses from answering your question, and in doing so I am in no way trying to insult you. If the link I posted did not answer your question, then please clarify the difference in a comment or the question itself, because as the question is currently worded I see no difference between it and the link I posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18689/discussion-between-diecho-and-theschwa).

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "I messed up, go back to last state".

You either need to know the permissions the file / directory had before or look up that information somewhere. If you don't have access to that information, you're out of luck.

#### Always make backups!